# How is this expression evaluated? (Also, what is it?)

Tags: c

I found this statement in header file that came with a micro controller and have no idea how to evaluate it

```
#define FIO0SET        (*(volatile unsigned long *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x18))
```

I don't have the foggiest idea what this expression is, and so I have no way to start any meaningful research. Can anyone tell me what this beast is or how to evaluate it?

Comment: It is a macro definition.

Comment: Use the FIO_BASE_ADDR (probably defined as some integer), add 0x18 (integer, hexa form), and cast it to pointer, then dereference it (access data from the address FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x18) as unsigned long (32-bit?).

Comment: I'm guessing its accessing a register from a memory mapped device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define FIO0SET  (*(volatile unsigned long *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x18))
```

Go at memory address `FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x18` and retreive the 32-bit (if `unsigned long` is 32-bit) word stored at that location. `FIO0SET` is also a modifiable lvalue so you can assign it a value.

Note that the `volatile` qualifier is used to inform the compiler that the value of the object can change in a way unknown to it. Consider for an example an IO register in input mode: its value can change unexpectedly and the compiler cannot assume its value didn't change after it was read.

For example:

```
unsigned long register_value;

register_value = FIO0SET; // store FIO0SET in register_value object
```

or

```
FIO0SET = 0x1122334;      // store 0x1122334 value in FIO0SET register
```

Comment: `volatile` tells the compiler that the value can change from an external source outside the source code.

Comment: @PeterGluck: More specifically, it tells the compiler not to cache the value.  Every time that `FIO0SET` is accessed, the compiler is required to generate code that performs the real memory access.

Comment: I added a paragraph to cover the use of the `volatile` qualifier in the macro.

Comment: @ouah Thanks for the quick answer and good information, this helps a lot.